# XPath how to select nodes by attribute name if the attribute name has a namespace

Tags: xml, xpath

I know I can select nodes by attribute name using

```
//*[@attribute]
```

But how do I do it if my attribute is a namespace like `bar:resource`?

For example:

```
<foo:creator bar:resource="https://example/john">john</foo:creator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much same stuff:

```
//*[@bar:resource]
```

This XPath selects all nodes which have `@bar:resource` attribute. To use this, you need to pass namespace uri and namespace prefix (`bar`) into your XML/XPath engine/processor.

Alternatively you can use pure XPath (although I don't recommend this):

```
//*[@*[local-name() = 'resource' and namespace-uri() = 'bar_namespace_uri']]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't recommend doing a `//*[@*[local-name() = 'resource']]` select?

Comment: @vinhboy, first of all, this XPath `//*[@*[local-name() = 'resource']]` doesn't check namespace of the attribute, i.e. `resource=""` and `bar:resource=""` both have local-name `resource`.

Comment: @vinhboy, which means, to make it consistent with `//*[@bar:resource]` you also need to check namespace of the attribute, e.g.: `//*[@*[local-name() = 'resource' and namespace-uri() = 'bar_namespace_uri']]`. I don't recommend this approach in terms of maintenance and flexibility: imagine you have many queries which all need to check namespace. This means in every query you need to specify namespace uri, which leads to code duplication, potential errors, etc.